# how does different variables pass through internet

Tags: xml, json, variables

Well, i bit confusion here regarding the conversions of variables passed through internet.

As far as i know, all the values submitted from web browser are converted in bits(0 1) as they pass throught different OSI layes. And than these bits are transfered over the internet. Here my question is does the Bits get converted again to their respective variable types at the server end? Plus the vise versa should be happening too, right? I mean, when a value is sent from server and received at client end?

Again, i know that XML and JSON are faster than passing a string value. Here i am again confused. If all values are converted to their bit/byte, than how come the XML/JSON is faster than simple string, if i send the same values? I mean comparison between sending a simple String and converting the String to its XML/JSON.

Can anyone please clear up my confusiona?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Again, i know that XML and JSON are faster than passing a string value.

You know **wrong** then and your confusion is **right**. Anyone who tells you that a string enclosed within more characters will be transferred faster over the internet is wrong.

If a string had length = 10 and you converted it into xml and made it length 30 and if each character took 1 byte then you just converted 10 bytes into 30 bytes and multiply that with 8 you just converted 80 bits into 240 bits. How can those be transferred faster? Calculate yourself :)

But its not just the speed that you need. Consider having to fetch order details from Amazon, won't you want things formatted so you can convert those into your variables easily? Or you want to parse a string dump without any formatting?. That's where those formats come in handy amongst their other benefits.

Comment: thanks. this is the same thing i was thinking too. In xml/Json the total btyes will get much more than usual String.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the basic idea. Communication on the internet works through a stack of protocol layers, often named according to the OSI reference model. At the top level (application level) you've got things like invoices and hotel bookings, at the bottom level you've got voltages on the wire. The invoices and hotel bookings are represented in some syntax such as XML or JSON (the badly-named presentation layer), these map to a sequence of characters, which maps to a sequence of octets, which maps to a sequence of ones and zeros, which map down to voltages. So on the sending end, you go down the stack to convert the invoice into voltage changes, and on the receiving end, you back up the stack to convert voltage changes into invoices. Of course, intermediaries like routers will also be involved along the way, typically doing partial decoding and re-encoding of the message for different transmission protocols such as ethernet and Wifi.

Speed depends on two things: how many bits are you sending down the wire, and how much time do you spend converting your invoice into bits and then back again. There are many trade-offs here, for example if you compress data then you will spend less time transmitting bits, but more time doing the conversions.

At the top layers, when choosing how to represent an invoice (XML, JSON, or some other syntax), speed is not usually the most important factor. Designers of messages at this level are usually more concerned with the flexibility and extensibility of the representation, the ease of generating and parsing the messages, the ability to validate the message against schema rules, and so on.